# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password_reset/

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-2.1

I'm working on authentication for a Django project I'm working on. For some reasons, I'm getting the error `Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` I put everything authentication in an `accounts` app.

Here's the content of the base `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from accounts import urls as accounts_urls
from core import urls as core_urls
from core import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include(accounts_urls, namespace='accounts')),
    path('core/', include(core_urls, namespace='core')),
]
```

Here's the content of the `urls.py` file (in the accounts app):

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views as accounts_views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', accounts_views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('account_activation_sent/', accounts_views.account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', accounts_views.activate, name='activate'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset.html',
        email_template_name='accounts/password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='accounts/password_reset_subject.txt'
    ), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'
    ), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'
    ), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'
    ), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Here's the `accounts/templates` directory structure:

- templates/

  - accounts/

    - password_reset.html
    - password_reset_email.html
    - password_reset_done.html
    - password_reset_confirm.html
    - password_reset_complete.html

I don't see anything wrong with what I have done so far. Any eye opener would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `namespace='accounts'` when you already have `app_name = 'accounts'` in the `urls.py`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out! Since I wanted to have more control over URLs, I changed the default Password Reset patterns. I was also bent on using namespaces so I changed the default `success_url` attribute in PasswordResetView and PasswordResetConfirmView to use the namespace. Here's what I mean:

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
# Add other necessary imports

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [    
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset.html',
        email_template_name='accounts/password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='accounts/password_reset_subject.txt',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')
    ), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'
    ), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_<uidb64>_<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')
    ), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'
    ), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Caspian I believe, you found the solution to my problem,

Moving from Django 2.0 to 2.1, I was going nuts trying to correct my password app to the new required configuration... I could not understand the problem... I did not improve on your solution, but here are my URL codes and it does confirm introducing "success_url=reverse_lazy" your solution works great.

```
path('password_reset/', 
    PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='app98/password_reset.html',
    email_template_name='app98/password_reset_email.html',
    subject_template_name='app98/password_reset_subject.txt',
    success_url=reverse_lazy('ns_app98:password_reset_done')), 
    name='password_reset'),

path('password_reset_done/', 
    PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
    template_name='app98/password_reset_done.html'), 
    name='password_reset_done'),

path('password_reset_<uidb64>_<token>/', 
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='app98/password_reset_confirm.html',
    success_url=reverse_lazy('app98:password_reset_complete')), 
    name='password_reset_confirm'),

path('password_reset_complete/', 
    PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
    template_name='app98/password_reset_complete.html'), 
    name='password_reset_complete'),
```

]

Answer (score 1):

Because your `password_reset_done` is namespaced under `accounts`, you need to be reversing `accounts:password_reset_done`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Django auth views do not use a namespace [when reversing urls](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L213). This means that it doesn't work with your current urls, since you have `app_name = 'account'` and `namespace='accounts'`.

The simplest solution is to remove the `accounts` app name and namespace (or move the password URL patterns into a different `urls.py` that doesn't have a namespace.

It is possible to subclass the password views and reverse using a namespace, but there's quite a lot of changes required.

Comment: I had to remove both `app_name=accounts` and `namespace=accounts` for it to work.